# Wordpress 5.1 and Syntax highlighter, problem with HTML encoded special characters

Tags: shortcode, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I'm using Wordpress 5.1 and Gutenberg block editor. I'm trying to show some Java code with the plugin SyntaxHighlighter Evolved. When editing a post I use the block 'Custom HTML' then add the code

```
[code language="java"]
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
[/code]
```

Then I save the post and the Java code will appear correctly with syntax highlighting applied to it. It will look like this

[image]

This is the result that I wanted. But a problem happens when I edit the post again, in the Wordpress editing the Custom HTML block changes to the following

```
[code language="java"]
List&lt;Integer&gt; myList = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;();
[/code]
```

The < and > signs have been replaced by &lt; and &gt; and the code on the website becomes

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the "SyntaxHighlighter Code" block?

Comment: @SallyCJ The SyntaxHighlighter block worked! Thanks a lot